# Converting from myisam to innodb

Tags: mysql, innodb, myisam

I am looking to convert my myisam mysql database to an innodb. I seem to keep coming up with conflicting ideas on how to do this or even if I should! What are your thoughts?

Comment: Dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1152437/how-to-convert-myisam-to-innodb

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change each table one by one?

```
alter table ... engine = InnoDB;
```